# How do we say "in all angles" idiomatically?

Tags: idiomatic-language

> There's a sphere **in all degrees of which** there are smaller spheres, and
>   thus forming a bigger sphere.

"In all degrees of which" sounds non-idiomatic. I think it's correct and it's easy to understand what it means from the context, but there's a more succinct way to say it, but I don't know how.

Comment: I can't form an image of the construction you're trying to describe. Could you provide a sketch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, I would say:

> There is a sphere **at all degrees**, there are smaller spheres, thus forming **a larger** sphere.